# Maximum oven temperature for glass cookware

Tags: baking, cookware, glass, kitchen-safety

Is there a maximum safe temperature for cooking with a glass casserole dish in an oven?

Got some Dutch ovens on the bottom rack at 240C (450F) and wondering if I dare put a Pyrex dish on the top rack for half an hour...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this page](https://www.hunker.com/13419098/can-pyrex-go-in-a-400-degree-oven)

> The Pyrex heat capacity is truly impressive as the glass can withstand temperatures up to 932 degrees Fahrenheit

or 500°C

Beware, however

> Pyrex will tolerate both hot and cold, but it can't do both at the same time. Pyrex can go from the freezer or fridge to the oven, but the trip needs to be a long one. Sudden changes in temperature can shatter any glass, including Pyrex

[This Pyrex beaker](https://www.sciencecompany.com/PYREX-Glass-Beaker-1000mL-P6182.aspx) has a temperature tolerance of 490°C, for instance.

Answer (score 3):

A glass casserole dish, with a casserole in it, will be safe at any temperature your oven can reach.

As Ring mentioned, the issue is not absolute temperature, but fast changes in temperature, leading to a temperature differential and thermal stresses inside the dish. Your oven cannot heat the dish fast enough to cause a problem, and the wet food inside will prevent the dish from going far above 100C, meaning that cooling it down afterwards will also be safe.

If you're using the dish to roast dry ingredients, or otherwise won't have food keeping the dish cool, it'll still be safe, but afterwards make sure to let it cool a bit before running cold water over it.

And remember the first rule for avoiding burns: **HOT GLASS LOOKS LIKE COLD GLASS**. Pay attention and don't pick it up with your bare hands once it's out of the oven.